# Need help in improving performance in running queries in sqlite database(android) while receiving query as Json from server

Tags: java, android, performance, sqlite

I have different type of Queries in a Hashmap ,and I need to run all the queries in sqlite db (in android db).

> > like   iterate hashmap {
> >                           // running query
> >     }

for large number of queries ,like

> 1. updating 1000 records using primary key reference took 15 sec.
> 2. updating 1000 records using where clause (5 conditions) took 212 sec.

I can't use transaction ,since I am receiving a query as a json param from server .
How can I do this efficiently with faster performance?

Comment: Use ORMlite database to make your db queries performance better and to make json parsing faster use GSON for this.

Answer (score 0):

Without transactions, this will not get any faster. SQLite performance (on Android and in general) is *very* poor.
do you use any ORM libray? If not, you might try prepared statements.